# Spring boot standalone runs well on local but cannot be accessed on remote server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I implemented a hello world in spring boot.

I am using embedded tomcat and here is my setting in the application.properties.

```
server.contextPath=/test
server.port=8080
```

I can access it at `[localhost:8080/test/index.html]` without problem.

However, after I upload the jar file to the ubuntu 14.04 on digital ocean and start it normally, I am not able to access it at `[machine-ipaddress:8080/test/index.html]`. It gives me a 404 error.

I can see the application listening to the port.

```
tcp    0    0    0.0.0.0:8080    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    4284/java
```

I checked iptable setting and nothing is blocked.

I also tried stop this and run a regular empty tomcat on the remote server and I have no problem accessing `[machine-ipaddress:8080]`.

Any ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The cause is that **I used maven webapp archetype to create the empty project, put index.html under webapp and package it as a jar**.

The weird thing is that I can use java -jar test.jar to run it locally.

Once I move index.html to resources/static, it can run on the remote server.